# How I can dowload GIF image in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing some tumblr client. And i want to download all photos in dashboard and save them to documentDirectory. Some of them is jpg some are gif. I have successfully download jpg images with this code:

```
do {
        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(fname)
        if let pngImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage!) {
            try pngImageData.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
            print(fname + " - saved")
        }
    } catch {print(fname + " - not saved") }
```

myImage is the image which is downloaded from URL. This code is work for jpg images but not good for gifs.

And lastly i read these files with this:

```
let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let filePath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(fname).path
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
        return UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath)!
    }
```

It's work for jpg but not for gifs. when i try this writing/reading codes on gifs images, i got just image not animation.

Can you show me the way pls with an example will be awesome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally used [this](https://github.com/kiritmodi2702/GIF-Swift) tinnie tool for GIFs. Simply add the *iOSDevCenters+GIF.swift* file directly to your project and use it as shown below

**1. Online URL**

```
    let imageURL = UIImage.gifImageWithURL(gifURL)
    let yourImageView = UIImageView(image: imageURL)
```

**2. Local Filename**

```
    let imageName = UIImage.gifImageWithName(imageName)
    let yourImageView = UIImageView(image: imageName)
```

**3. Using Data**

```
    let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "name", withExtension: ".gif"))
    let imageData = UIImage.gifImageWithData(imageData)
    let yourImageView = UIImageView(image: imageData)
```

Comment: @erhirima It downloads, but you didn't mentioned about saving (into photo gallery)

Answer (score 3):

Actually your first code is not working correctly either.

What you are receiving *is* the image. You do not need or want to *translate* it into some other kind of image (`UIImagePNGRepresentation`). Just save the *data*. Later, read the *data* directly into a UIImage.

Comment: matt, Thank you!. I saved with image with only data(not as image file) and load image with this data. It worked!. That's a good idea thank you again

Comment: Using UIImagePNGRepresentation & UIImageJPEGRepresentation you will lose GIF image.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem with downloading and you are just trying to present it as a png; instead try to present this saved data with [this library](https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif/), for example

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#import AssetsLibrary

let lib = ALAssetsLibrary()

let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: getCurrentGIFURL)

lib.writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum(data, metadata: nil) { (url, err) in

    }
```